# expressionengine 500 error on general configuration

Tags: php, expressionengine

I am getting 500 error on attempt to open General configuration page on admin side. Nothing in error logs. I tried to find the line where it fails and figured that it dies on

```
$details[] = array('name' => $name, 'value' => $k, 'id' => $name.'_'.$k, 'label' => $v, 'checked' => ee()->form_validation->set_radio($name, $k, $checked));
```

of EE_config.php line 1577.

After that line nothing happen and seems failing. I opened Form_validation file and tried debug the point of die but seems it working just fine

```
function set_radio($field = '', $value = '', $default = FALSE)
{
    if ( ! isset($this->_field_data[$field]) OR ! isset($this->_field_data[$field]['postdata']))
    {
        if ($default === TRUE AND count($this->_field_data) === 0)
        {
            return ' checked="checked"';
        }
        return '';
    }
```

So it returns ' checked="checked"' and after that throws 500 error. Maybe called some magic functions after? Can you give me an idea?

System is php 7, EE 2.11.9.

Comment: Check error logs and find the __exact__ reason of your error.

Comment: I wrote that checked log, there is no error

Comment: I would look at /system/expressionengine/config/config.php to see if there is anything unexpected there.  The CP page you are referring to pulls some of its values from there.